# Catch send mail event outlook web app add in

Tags: office365-apps, outlook-web-app, outlook-web-addins

I'm working on outlook web app add in. Is there any way to catch event when email is sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, this is an unsupported scenario. However, we are working on new APIs all the time, and this may be supported in the near future. Keep an eye on our announcements and check [dev.outlook.com](http://dev.outlook.com) for updates!